# Why is 'Go Back' button not working in Django?

Tags: html, css, django, button, django-forms

I am currently building an image description writing website. Tools/langs I use are html, css, django, and javascript. The problem is, when I click on the 'Go back' button on the html provided below, it doesn't redirect me to the previous mission-acting-writing page (account:write_page_url) but stays at the mission-acting-finish.html. 'Posting' and 'Image' are the models stored in models.py. 'Posting' stores every info user enters when writing one's post, and 'Image' stores individual image files extracted from the image zip file user has provided when writing the post. I've been struggling with this problem for the past 20 hours nonsleep. Please identify the problem in the code. Thank you so much in advance!

Here is the code of my function 'end' in views.py:

```
def end(request, posting_id, image_index):
    posting = get_object_or_404(Posting, id=posting_id)

    user_detail, created = UserDetail.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.POST.get('action')

        if action == 'complete':
            total_reward = request.session.get('total_reward', 0)
            user_detail.point += total_reward
            user_detail.save()
            request.session['total_images'] = 0
            request.session['total_reward'] = 0
            request.session['image_index'] = 0
            request.session['listlength'] = posting.remaining_count
            return redirect('account:explore')
        
    context = {
        'total_images': request.session.get('total_images', 0),
        'total_reward': request.session.get('total_reward', 0),
        'posting_id': posting_id,
        'image_index': image_index,
    }
    request.session.pop('image_ids', None)
    return render(request,'mission-acting-finish.html',context)`
```

Here is a section of my mission-acting-finish.html:

```
    <main class="main-wrapper">
      <header class="section_product-header">
        <div class="w-layout-blockcontainer w-container">
          <h1 class="heading-4">{{posting.title}}</h1>
          <div class="requirements finish">
            <p class="paragraph-8 finish">You have finished {{total_images}} image descriptions!<br>The expected reward is <strong>${{total_reward}}</strong>.<br>Are you sure to exit?</p>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'account:end' posting_id=posting_id image_index=image_index %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="finish-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="complete" class="button button-2 distance w-button">End</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div>
              <a href="{% url 'account:write_page_url' posting_id=posting_id image_index=image_index %}" class="button distance w-button">Go back</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </main>
```

I tried 'elif action == "return":' and so forth, including the 'Go back' button in the form (in html) and renaming it as "return". Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: when you submit the form, you are sent to other page, even that page is same as current page,
so you should submit the form with ajax, that's how your page won't change and go-back button would work as expected